# How to implement my code to send password reset link?

Tags: java, android, firebase

I'm making a shopping App and I've almost finished the App. But I wanted to add the Forget password feature after all. I could've done it using FirebaseAuth but for registration and login, I haven't used FirebaseAuth.

My user details are going straight to the firebase database and are being saved in the Users table. Since I'm new to android app developing I don't know how to implement my app with forget password feature.

This is my database structure : [image: database]

This is my **RegisterActivity:**

```
public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button CreateAccountButton;
    private EditText InputUsername, InputPhoneNumber, InputPassword, InputRePassword, InputEmail, InputName;
    private ProgressDialog loadingBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
        CreateAccountButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register_btn);
        InputUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.register_username);
        InputPhoneNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.register_Number);
        InputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.register_password);
        InputRePassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.register_repassword);
        InputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.register_email);
        InputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.register_name);
        loadingBar = new ProgressDialog(this);
        CreateAccountButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                CreateAccount();
            }
        });
    }

    private void CreateAccount() {
        String name = InputName.getText().toString();
        String username = InputUsername.getText().toString();
        String phone = InputPhoneNumber.getText().toString();
        String password = InputPassword.getText().toString();
        String repassword = InputRePassword.getText().toString();
        String email = InputEmail.getText().toString();

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(name)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter your Name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(username)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter your Username", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(phone)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter your Phone Number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter your Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(repassword)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please re-enter your Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter your Email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            loadingBar.setTitle("Creating Account");
            loadingBar.setMessage("Please wait.");
            loadingBar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            loadingBar.show();
            ValidatephoneNumber(username, name, phone, password, repassword, email);
        }
    }

    private void ValidatephoneNumber(final String username, final String name, final String phone, final String password, final String repassword, final String email)
    {
        final DatabaseReference RootRef;
        RootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        RootRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
            {
                if(!(dataSnapshot.child("Users").child(username).exists()))
                {
                    HashMap<String, Object> userdataMap = new HashMap<>();
                    userdataMap.put("username", username);
                    userdataMap.put("name", name);
                    userdataMap.put("phone", phone);
                    userdataMap.put("password", password);
                    userdataMap.put("email", email);
                    RootRef.child("Users").child(username).updateChildren(userdataMap)
                            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task)
                                {
                                    if(task.isSuccessful())
                                    {
                                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Your account has been created!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        loadingBar.dismiss();
                                        Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                                        startActivity(intent);
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        loadingBar.dismiss();
                                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Connection Error. Please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,"This Username already exists! Try another Username", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError)
            {
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And here's my **LoginActivity:**

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private EditText InputUsername, InputPassword;
private Button LoginButton;
private ProgressDialog loadingBar;
private String parentDbName = "Users";
private CheckBox chkBoxRememberMe;
private TextView AdminLink, UserLink, ForgetPassword;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    LoginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.main_login_btn);
    InputUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_username);
    InputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    AdminLink = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.adminPanel);
    UserLink = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.userLogin);
    loadingBar = new ProgressDialog(this);
    chkBoxRememberMe = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.remember_me_chkb);
    ForgetPassword = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.forgetPassword);
    Paper.init(this);
    LoginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            LoginUser();
        }
    });
    AdminLink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            LoginButton.setText("Login Admin");
            AdminLink.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            UserLink.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            parentDbName = "Admins";
        }
    });
    UserLink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            LoginButton.setText("Login");
            AdminLink.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            UserLink.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            parentDbName = "Users";
        }
    });

    ForgetPassword.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ForgotPassowrdActivity.class));
        }
    });
}

private void LoginUser() {
    String username = InputUsername.getText().toString();
    String password = InputPassword.getText().toString();

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(username))
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter your Username", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password))
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter your Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else
    {
        loadingBar.setTitle("Logging in to the Account");
        loadingBar.setMessage("Please wait.");
        loadingBar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        loadingBar.show();
        AllowAccessToAccount(username, password);
    }
}

private void AllowAccessToAccount(final String username, final String password)
{
    if(chkBoxRememberMe.isChecked())
    {
        Paper.book().write(Prevelant.userUsernameKey, username);
        Paper.book().write(Prevelant.userPasswordKey,password);
    }

    final DatabaseReference RootRef;
    RootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    RootRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
        {
            if (dataSnapshot.child(parentDbName).child(username).exists())
            {
                Users usersData = dataSnapshot.child(parentDbName).child(username).getValue(Users.class);
                if(usersData.getUsername().equals(username))
                {
                    if(usersData.getPassword().equals(password))
                    {
                        if(parentDbName.equals("Admins"))
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Welcome Admin, You've logged in successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            loadingBar.dismiss();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, AdminCategoryActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                        else if(parentDbName.equals("Users"))
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Logged in successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            loadingBar.dismiss();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                            Prevelant.currentOnlineUser = usersData;
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "This Password is incorrect!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        loadingBar.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "This Username is not registered!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                loadingBar.dismiss();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError)
        {
        }
    });
}
```

}

Can I please know how to implement my code for forget password feature? I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

This comes inbuilt with firebase:

`FirebaseAuth.getInstance().sendPasswordResetEmail("user@example.com")`

Comment: Yeah, I haven't used it for my App tho. So is there a way that I can add it to my App without affecting anything?

Comment: @HarithaMadushanka I mean you just need to pass in the email for it to send. You can add clauses for what to do on success etc.